# How do I get the table header to span the whole table when using display properties to emulate a <table>?

Tags: html, css

I have replaced an old table with a new one made out of Divs and everything works fine except for one thing. 
I want to have a header that is Spanning over the hole width of the Table but not as in the table-heading css clas where you have multiple cells in the heading. 
I just cant get it to work I tried colspan but since this isnt a thing for divtables this did not work.

Here is a small example of my table.

```css
.divTableCell{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">3</div>
  </div>
```

Everytime I tried to create the Header with the Talbe-heading class it only would fit over the Left Tablecell.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make the header a table-caption. See example below:

```css
.divTableCell{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
}
.table {
    display: table;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}
.header {
    display: table-caption;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
  <div class="table">
  <div class="header"> This is a test</div>
  <div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">3</div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.divTableCell{
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 50%;
}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
    width: 100%;
}

<div style="width:100%;">
<div style="border:1px solid #000;" ><b>header</b></div>
<div class="divTableRow">
    <div class="divTableCell">1</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">2</div>
    <div class="divTableCell">3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: or try using css bootstrap for responsive layout